# Libserial 1.0 library: linker cannot find methods

Tags: linker-errors, libserial

I downloaded and built libserial 1.0 from  https://libserial.readthedocs.io  to my OpenSuse Leap 15.3.
To test the functionality, I built a small program:

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
        LibSerial::SerialStream serial_port;
        const std::string sourcePort="/dev/ttyUSB0";
        serial_port.Open(sourcePort);
        serial_port.Close();
        return(0);
}
```

now, when I compile with

```
g++  -std=gnu++11    /home/thomas/Downloads/libserial/lib/libserial.a   -I /home/thomas/Downloads/libserial/src main.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccT8Z1h6.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SerialStream()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::_Ios_Openmode const&)'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Close()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::~SerialStream()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::~SerialStream()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It almost seems like the linker cannot  find the function in the static library.
Can anyone point out why that would be ? I really want to link statically.

Thanks much,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that libserial 1.0 needs at least C++ 14. That did not help with the error message, though.

I ended up using the source files directly, i.e. not building the library but including SerialStream.cpp, SerialPort.cpp and  SerialConstants.cpp directly. It compiled without errors.